# how to apply mass delete java script function for deleting specific record type in case

Tags: javascript, custom-button, record-type, list-button

I am using mass delete list button.I am using following code for mass delete:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
var selectedRecords = {!GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.Case)}; 
sforce.connection.deleteIds(selectedRecords); 
navigateToUrl(window.location.href);
```

I am able to delete cases irrespective of record type. But can anyone tell me how can I do this for a specific record type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this for a specific record type, you'd have to retrieve the records first:

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js")}
var recordIds = {!GetRecordIds($ObjectType.Case)};
var records = sforce.connection.retrieve("Id,RecordType.Name", "Case", recordIds);
recordIds = [];
records.forEach(function(value) {
  if(value.RecordType && value.RecordType.Name === "Some Record Type") {
    recordIds.push(value.Id);
  }
});
sforce.connection.deleteIds(recordIds);
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: {!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js")}
var recordIds = {!GetRecordIds($ObjectType.Case)};
var records = sforce.connection.retrieve("Id,RecordType.Name", "Case", recordIds);
recordIds = [];
records.forEach(function(value) {
  if(value.RecordType.Name === "AdOpsTech") {
    recordIds.push(value.Id);
  }
});
sforce.connection.deleteIds(recordIds);
window.location.reload();

Comment: when i tried the above code snippet for "AdOpsTech" record type i am getting the below errors..."Errors:
• Enter a URL that is valid and well-formed
• Function REQUIRESCRIPT may not be used in this type of formula"Please let me know what changes are to be done this..
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: @Gmi you need to use the onclick behavior instead of URL.

Comment: @sfdcfox...i am not getting where can i use Onclick instead of URL.Could you please help me the change in code snippet. Thanks..

Comment: @Gmi in the Behavior dropdown when creating the button, one choice should be OnClick JavaScript.

Comment: @Sfdcfox...The button for deleting specific record type is only working for Sys Admin.When i tried in user level its throwing an error "A Problem for onliclick javascript was encountered..--cannot read property 'Name' of null" Could you please help me how can i resolve this

Comment: {!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js")} var recordIds = {!GetRecordIds($ObjectType.Case)}; var records = sforce.connection.retrieve("Id,RecordType.Name", "Case", recordIds); recordIds = []; records.forEach(function(value) { if(value.RecordType.Name === "AdOpsTech") { recordIds.push(value.Id); } }); sforce.connection.deleteIds(recordIds); window.location.reload();

Comment: @Gmi Do you have records using the "Master Record Type"? You might need to do this instead: `if(value.RecordType && value.RecordType.Name === "AdOpsTech")`

Comment: the error is not visible now but multiple records are not getting deleted @sfdcfox

Comment: @Gmi I didn't include any error handling, so you'll want to [read more about that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_errors.htm). You should check the return value from the call to make sure it actually succeeded.